# Jquery Mobile 1.45 table reflow - Landscape mode view not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with Table reflow of JQM - On landscape mode the table content is displayed as it is on portrait mode (one column view), instead of showing all columns spreading to the width of the screen. 
It happens only in some devices (i.e. Galaxy s2 and on Samsung Grand).
I will really appreciate any help...

Comment: Please, can you share some code?